# Widget test a widget which uses WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm trying to do a widget test in flutter to one widget which uses [WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) to show a dialog at the very beggining of the widget lifecycle.

The widget works fine, but I cannot figure out how to do a widget test, because the very first expect() of the test is executed before this post frame is triggered.

Anyway to "tell" the test to wait until all the post frames are dispatched?

PD: tester.pump(), tester.pumpAndSettle(), etc. are **not** working.

Comment: I have the same issue and sorry to say I have no idea ;-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But what do you know... suddenly it popped up:

```
    tester.binding.scheduleWarmUpFrame();
```

Run that :-)

Taken from here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/flutter/+/v0.9.2/packages/flutter/test/widgets/binding_test.dart

Comment: warmUpFrame is not exactly what you need, bc it has some initialization overhead

Answer (score 4):

To schedule a frame (and force `postFrameCallback` to be called) in flutter test environment you need to call `tester.binding.scheduleFrame()` before `tester.pump()`.

Alternatively, if you don't care about the whole widget tree being rebuilt, you could call `tester.pumpWidget(widget)` instead of `tester.pump()`

Example test:

```dart
testWidgets('testing frames', (tester) async {
  final w = Container();
  int framesCount = 0;

  tester.binding.addPersistentFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    framesCount++;
  });

  await tester.pumpWidget(w);
  expect(framesCount, equals(1));

  // pumpWidget calls [scheduleFrame]
  await tester.pumpWidget(w);
  expect(framesCount, equals(2));

  await tester.pump();
  // no frame was scheduled, so framesCount is still 2
  expect(framesCount, equals(2));

  tester.binding.scheduleFrame(); // --
  await tester.pump();            //   |
  expect(framesCount, equals(3)); // <-

  // pumpWidget calls [scheduleFrame]
  await tester.pumpWidget(w);
  expect(framesCount, equals(4));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
// press button
await tester.tap(find.text("Save"));
// await the flushbar or snackbar to appear
await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 1));
// find by text or key
expect(find.text("Error saving note"), findsOneWidget);
// this prevents this error:
// A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed.
// the flushbar in my code is displayed for 5 seconds. So we wait for it to 
// go away.
await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 5));
```

I dont know if this is the proper way to do. But it works.
Good luck!